# HTML - What is the difference between HTML and user defined attributes?

Tags: html

What is the difference between HTML and user defined attributes? Please see code snippet below -

```
<button name="send" data-name="send_button"></button>
```

where name - HTML attribute
and data-name - user defined attribute

Please also correct if I did not use the right terms for the attributes!

Comment: One attribute is called `name` and the other is called `data-name`. Nothing more, nothing less. What's confusing to you about this?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5, you define custom attributes using the "data" attribute. The exact format is "data-thing", where "thing" is replaced with the desired custom attribute name, then set to the desired string value. For example:

`<div id="mydiv" data-brand="toyota" data-model="prius">John is very happy with his Toyota Prius, because he saves on gas.</div>`

Your attribute name must be prefixed with "data-" in order to validate in HTML 5. So in other words, while HTML 5 supports custom attributes, it doesn't allow for arbitrary attribute names.

The appeal of custom attributes is that it lets you easily associate tidbits of information with an element, to be parsed later using JavaScript or jQuery for example.

This is extremely popular as a practice amongst plugins as it allows for a simple method of defining specifics without by simply grabbing it from the HTML document. This can be seen in wow.js through its use easy of `data-wow-duration=".2s"`

Comment: Can you pls explain the last part, where you said its useful in plugins

Comment: It makes it easy for plugins to allow you to define attributes (since they can be found easily using javascript), such as an animations duration for the selected HTML element without having to have you write any javascript yourself or have to modify the original code. I hope this helps.